# 5 Ghz wifi get 30Mbps on 200Mbps line, 2.4 Ghz gets 60Mbps. No congestion on channel

Tags: wireless-router, internet-speed

I need some help determining the issue of my setup. Here is a summary:

- Wired to router I get 200Mbps
- 2.4Ghz I get 80Mbps, its on a channel with some neighbors, but it's using 40mhz bandwidth. Btw, when I put it on channel 13 for test, I get 120Mbps :O
- 5Ghz I get 30Mbps, its on a channel without any other signals. My router only has the "20/40mhz" bandwidth option for it
- all tests done in the same small room with no obstruction, same results literally right next to the modem
- I'm running padavan on my asus rt-n56u, load on the cpu is minimal
- only a couple active connections, nothing really loading the network

I'm confused why my 5Ghz is performing so badly even with everything ideal. Do I just need a better router?

Comment: Define "ideal". Are you in the middle of a city with a large number of nearby electronic devices or are you in the countryside? Are you in a room with a lot of metal (wall cladding, etc) nearby or are your walls a relatively thin wood with nothing nearby? There are a lot of things that can affect electromagnetic wave propagation and reflection and it's hard to say a "small room" is ideal. Or it could just be that the router has a bad 5GHz antenna, is poorly designed, or that the connector is loose.

Comment: You may also be using wider channels on 2.4 GHz than 5.  That could be a configuration issue.  It could also be a limitation of the router, or your test computer, or both.

Comment: 2x2 HT40 with good signal on a clean channel should get the 300Mbps PHY rate, which should translate into 180+ Mbps throughput from wired to wireless. You're only getting 30Mbps which is quite low, and in fact within the range of 802.11a. It makes me wonder if you've disabled WMM (a.k.a. 802.11e, wireless QoS; it's required by 802.11n), or if you're using WEP or original WPA security, which 802.11n forbids (802.11n requires WPA2 or better, or no wireless security at all).

Comment: @Mokubai I ran the test next to the router, I would hope that is ideal and cut out most of the issue. I live in a suburb and theres plenty of other wifi, but like I mentioned, there's nothing else on my 5ghz channel.

Comment: @Spiff good point, I'm pretty sure those are configured correctly but I will double check thanks

Comment: @mugetsu being right next to the router could lead to the receiver being saturated and effectively "blinded" by the signal brightness leading to degradation of speed. Reflections can cause additional as well as similar problems due to poor timing. Hence the local environment *is* important.